# AWS CloudFront Function add Security Headers to un-cached responses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, response-headers

**Problem summary:**

CloudFront Function cannot be associated with *origin response events*, just with *viewer request* and *viewer response events*. Thus, I cannot manage to set security headers to requests served from the server (not cached ones).

**Is there any way to do this with CloudFront Functions instead of lambda@edge functions?**

**Problem details:**

I have a CloudFront Cache behavior with a lamda@edge function associated to add Security Headers to responses. This lambda@edge function is triggered with an *origin response event* and set several Security Headers. It seems to work properly (checking headers with chrome developer tools and with https://securityheaders.com/). However, I would like to change this lambda@edge function by a CloudFront Function (following these examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-add-security-headers.html and https://how.wtf/deploy-cloudfront-functions-to-add-security-headers-with-aws-cdk.html).

The problem I´m facing is that the CloudFront Function cannot be associated with *origin response events*, just with *viewer request* and *viewer response events* (check aws documentation https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/associate-function.html). For this reason, I cannot add the security headers when the request is served from the server, only if the request is served from CloudFront Cache.

**How can I add security headers to origin response when the request is served from the server using CloudFront Functions?** I can manage to do it with lambda@edge functions, but I would like to do it with CloudFront Functions.

According to the AWS documentation (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudfront-trigger-events.html and https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/) requests to CloudFront follow the process described in the following image:

[image]

1. Viewer navigates to website.
2. Before CloudFront serves content from the cache it will trigger any Lambda function associated with the Viewer Request trigger for that behavior.
3. CloudFront serves content from the cache if available, otherwise, it goes to step 4.
4. Only after CloudFront cache ‘Miss’, Origin Request trigger is fired for that behavior.
5. S3 Origin returns content.
6. After content is returned from S3 but before being cached in CloudFront, the Origin Response trigger is fired.
7. After content is cached in CloudFront, the Viewer Response trigger is fired and is the final step before the viewer receives content.
8. Viewer receives content.

My Cloud Front Function works properly and sets the security headers when the path is 1, 2, 3, 7 & 8 (cached requests) but not when the path is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 & 8. My lambda@edge function works properly in both cases.

Comment: You can use a viewer-response event with CloudFront Functions to set the headers on all responses before they are returned to the viewer, regardless of whether or not the response came from CloudFront's cache. You can find example code for this here: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-functions/tree/main/add-security-headers

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Cristian. I have already tried with that function, indeed is the same as the one proposed in the AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-add-security-headers.html However, I still face the same issue. I think that the function works properly, it must be a configuration problem.

Comment: According to the documentation, it should work, as the viewer-response should be executed regardless of whether the response is served from cache or served from the origin. If you think it must be a configuration problem, can you share how it is configured? Or even have a minimal working example in cloudformation so we can test this ourselves?